# Github flow with two braches

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a setup with Laravel Vapor and Github Actions.
On Vapor there are 2 environments, staging and production.
On Github I have 2 branches, main and testing. When I push to main it deploys to production on Vapor and when I push to testing it deploys on staging.
My flow now is first I push to testing branch like this `git add . && git commit -m "Testing" && git push -u origin testing`
After testing I do `git checkout main && git merge testing` and `git push`.
This works well, only that on the testing branch it sais "This branch is 11 commits behind main." and after every push onto main the number increases.

I need one file to be different between branches, if it matters, it's the file that Github Actions uses `.github/workflows/deploy.yaml`.

Is that normal, to have the "commits behind" after each deploy? I'm guessing it's not ok, if so, how can I avoid it?

Comment: It **is** *normal* (under various conditions) because a merge is represented by a *merge commit*, and the merge commit causes the branch on which the merge is made to advance, so that this branch is now at least one commit ahead (and more in other cases). Whether you find it *desirable* is another question entirely. Note that a "fast-forward merge" (which is not a merge at all) avoids this by making two branch names identify the *same* commit, which is also normal, but again may or may not be undesirable. You must decide for yourself.

Comment: Note that I'm speaking only in terms of Git here. Any additional software such as Laravel might add its own constraints (but I don't use Laravel and you didn't tag this with Laravel).

Comment: @torek I don't think fast-forward merge is what I need since I need one file different between branches. If they have the same commit, it won't probably work.
So I guess it's ok how it is, there is no other way, that's how git works. Thanks.